# Want my google forms to send an email to the respondent email they entered to specific cell

Tags: google-forms

This the code I am using

```
function sendEmail(e) {
 //response
 //getRespondentEmail()

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlEmail.html")
  var htmlText = html.evaluate().getContent();

  var emailTo= e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var subject = "Thanks for participation";
  var textBody = "This email requires HTML support. Please make sure you open with a client that supports it."
  var options = { htmlBody : htmlText };

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("B!");
  if (emailTo!== undefined){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, textBody, options)
  }
}
```

However, the problem with this code that it relies on google getting the email (through a mandatory cell)
What I want is to make it optional for the particpant to enter their email or not in a specific cell.
Then I want the code to read that email in the specified cell and send an email to it.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking “How do I write an ‘if’ statement in a Google Script?” (If email address exists send out an email to that person, otherwise don’t...)

Comment: Kind of.
To explain it more, I want :
var emailTo= "to read the text in a specific cell in a google form"